# AssertionError while inserting errorbars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to insert errorbars into my barplot, but Im getting an error I dont really understand. I guess the solution is not that complicated, but I dont seem to find it, also while searching for similar problems in the forum.

```py
Curtailment_Herrenhof_A     = 12210
Curtailment_Herrenhof_B     = 22170
Curtailment_Herrenhof_data  = 8896
std = 2000



plt.figure
plt.bar('eff avg', Curtailment_Herrenhof_A, width = 0.5, label='Method A')
plt.bar('none', Curtailment_Herrenhof_B, width = 0.5, label='Method B')
plt.bar('wind avg', Curtailment_Herrenhof_data, width = 0.5, label='Measured data')
plt.errorbar('eff avg', Curtailment_Herrenhof_A, yerr= std, marker='o', fmt='') 
plt.ylabel('Durtaion of curtailment measures [min]', fontsize=12)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(-0.018, 1.2), loc='upper left', ncol=3)
plt.xticks([])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Curtailment_Wirdum_time.png')
plt.show()
```

with the error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Elias/Anaconda3/Scripts/Masterarbeit/plotten.py", line 213, in <module>
    plt.errorbar('eff avg', Curtailment_Herrenhof_A, yerr= std, marker='o', fmt='')

  File "C:\Users\Elias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2991, in errorbar
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Elias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1867, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Elias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 3324, in errorbar
    xo, _ = xywhere(x, lower, noylims & everymask)

  File "C:\Users\Elias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 3225, in xywhere
    assert len(xs) == len(ys)

AssertionError
```

So there seems to be some kind of a dimension error I dont really get? I am only trying to plot integers so I dont see the problem..

Maybe somebody can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing strings as first arguments everywhere? For example, [`pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)expects its first argument to be a "sequence of scalars", not a string. [Same thing for `errorbar`.](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar)

You're getting this particular error because here:

```
plt.errorbar('eff avg', Curtailment_Herrenhof_A, ...)
```

You're attempting to plot the string (!) `'eff avg'` against a single number `Curtailment_Herrenhof_A`, so, somewhere inside `matplotlib`, `xs == 'eff avg'` and `ys == [12210]`. Of course, `len('eff avg') != len([12210])`, so you get the error.

Also, `plt.figure` doesn't do anything. [It's a function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure), and it should be *called* to actually do something.

Comment: well... honestly: because it worked. Its the name of that bar. But yeah youre right, that was pretty much nonsense. It works if I just put scalars... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a string (e.g. `"abcde"`)  can be interpreted as a list of characters (`["a", "b", ...]`). It therefore also has a length. What you want however, is to treat the complete string as a single element of a list to be able to plot it against another value. So instead of `plt.bar("my string", 100)` you would want to put that string into a list with a single element.

```
plt.bar(["my string"], 100)
```

Your complete code:

```
Curtailment_Herrenhof_A     = 12210
Curtailment_Herrenhof_B     = 22170
Curtailment_Herrenhof_data  = 8896
std = 2000

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.bar(['eff avg'], Curtailment_Herrenhof_A, width = 0.5, label='Method A')
plt.bar(['none'], Curtailment_Herrenhof_B, width = 0.5, label='Method B')
plt.bar(['wind avg'], Curtailment_Herrenhof_data, width = 0.5, label='Measured data')
plt.errorbar(['eff avg'], Curtailment_Herrenhof_A, yerr= std, marker='o', fmt='') 
plt.ylabel('Durtaion of curtailment measures [min]', fontsize=12)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(-0.018, 1.2), loc='upper left', ncol=3)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Curtailment_Wirdum_time.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]